# How can I pass a datatable to the table data type in a stored procedure without creating type or looping?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I need to use the table data type to get data table without looping or creating type

As example like the following

Pass datatable from C# to `@tbl`

```
 create proc testtbl (@tbl TABLE (col nvarchar(50)))
 as 
 begin
     INSERT INTO tbl( column )
       SELECT col
       FROM @tbl
 end
```

Comment: Could you please specify what version / implementation of sql you are using?

Comment: i use sql 2008 - it's not possible to use table data type without creating type ?

Comment: I don't think so. You have some options: 1) concatenate your values with some delimiter (eg. pipe or comma) into a VARCHAR(MAX) and pass in the value ---- then parse the value in your proc. 2) Create an intermediate table with spid and col, populate it with values and the current spid, then pass the spid to your proc.